# return html.helper inside datatables

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Can this be done? I want to replace the id below to `oObj.aData[0]` but I don't see how. Anyone?

```
"sName": "MISC2",
"fnRender": function (oObj) {
return '@Html.ActionImage("GetTransportDocument", "Bookings", new { id = 1201 }, "~/Images /pdf16.png", "alttexten")'}
```

something like

```
return '@Html.ActionImage("GetTransportDocument", "Bookings", new { id = ' + oObj.aData[0]+ ' }, "~/Images/pdf16.png", "alttexten")'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, but you can try this out

```
function (oObj) {
    var url =  '@Html.ActionImage("GetTransportDocument", "Bookings", new { id = -1 }, "~/Images /pdf16.png", "alttexten")';
    return url.replace("-1", oObj.aData[0]);
}
```

variable `url` will be generated with `-1` value. Replace it with your desired value